# Unable to import any libraries in Jupyter notebook even after installing in my virtual environment

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, conda, virtual-environment

I have created this virtual environment `virtualenv`. and installed jupyter notebook over there.

```
conda create -p "C:\Users\HPO2KOR\Desktop\Work\venv\virtualenv" pip python=3.6
conda activate C:\Users\HPO2KOR\Desktop\Work\venv\virtualenv
ipython kernel install --user --name=virtualenv
```

Now when I am installing any package everything works fine.

```
(C:\Users\HPO2KOR\Desktop\Work\venv\virtualenv) C:\Users\HPO2KOR\Desktop\Work\venv\VTU>conda install selenium
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: done

# All requested packages already installed.
```

But when I am importing it in my jupyter notebook

```
(C:\Users\HPO2KOR\Desktop\Work\venv\virtualenv) C:\Users\HPO2KOR\Desktop\Work\venv\VTU>jupyter notebook
```

[image]

And its not only for selenium, it isn't working for any of the packages. How do I resolve this?

**Note :** I tried all suggestions to this question and none of the answers worked for me.

**EDIT :**
As asked by cel in the comments section.

```
# packages in environment at C:\Users\HPO2KOR\Desktop\Work\venv\virtualenv:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
absl-py                   0.9.0                    pypi_0    pypi
astor                     0.8.1                    pypi_0    pypi
atomicwrites              1.3.0                    pypi_0    pypi
attrs                     19.3.0                   pypi_0    pypi
bzip2                     1.0.6                    vc14_3  [vc14]  defaults
ca-certificates           2019.11.28           hecc5488_0    conda-forge
cachetools                4.0.0                    pypi_0    pypi
certifi                   2019.11.28               pypi_0    pypi
chardet                   3.0.4                    pypi_0    pypi
click                     7.0                      pypi_0    pypi
colorama                  0.4.3                    pypi_0    pypi
configobj                 5.0.6                    pypi_0    pypi
configparser              4.0.2                    pypi_0    pypi
cython                    0.29.15                  pypi_0    pypi
docx2txt                  0.8                      pypi_0    pypi
etelemetry                0.1.2                    pypi_0    pypi
filelock                  3.0.12                   pypi_0    pypi
gast                      0.2.2                    pypi_0    pypi
google-auth               1.10.1                   pypi_0    pypi
google-auth-oauthlib      0.4.1                    pypi_0    pypi
google-pasta              0.1.8                    pypi_0    pypi
grpcio                    1.26.0                   pypi_0    pypi
h5py                      2.10.0                   pypi_0    pypi
httplib2                  0.17.0                   pypi_0    pypi
idna                      2.8                      pypi_0    pypi
importlib-metadata        1.5.0                    pypi_0    pypi
imutils                   0.5.3                    pypi_0    pypi
jpeg                      9c                hfa6e2cd_1001    conda-forge
keras-applications        1.0.8                    pypi_0    pypi
keras-preprocessing       1.1.0                    pypi_0    pypi
labelimg                  1.8.3                    pypi_0    pypi
leptonica                 1.78.0               h919f142_2    conda-forge
libarchive                3.3.3                h798a506_0    defaults
libiconv                  1.15             vc14h29686d3_5  [vc14]  defaults
libpng                    1.6.37               h7602738_0    conda-forge
libtiff                   4.1.0                h21b02b4_3    conda-forge
libwebp                   1.0.2                hfa6e2cd_5    conda-forge
libxml2                   2.9.10               h9ce36c8_0    conda-forge
lxml                      4.5.0                    pypi_0    pypi
lz4-c                     1.8.3             he025d50_1001    conda-forge
lzo                       2.10             vc14h0a64fa6_1  [vc14]  defaults
markdown                  3.1.1                    pypi_0    pypi
minecart                  0.3.0                    pypi_0    pypi
mocr                      0.3.0                    pypi_0    pypi
more-itertools            8.2.0                    pypi_0    pypi
nibabel                   3.0.1                    pypi_0    pypi
numpy                     1.18.1                   pypi_0    pypi
oauthlib                  3.1.0                    pypi_0    pypi
opencv-contrib-python     4.2.0.32                 pypi_0    pypi
opencv-python             4.2.0.32                 pypi_0    pypi
openjpeg                  2.3.1                h57dd2e7_3    conda-forge
openssl                   1.0.2u               hfa6e2cd_0    conda-forge
opt-einsum                3.1.0                    pypi_0    pypi
packaging                 20.1                     pypi_0    pypi
pandas                    1.0.1                    pypi_0    pypi
pdfminer3k                1.3.1                    pypi_0    pypi
pillow                    7.0.0                    pypi_0    pypi
pip                       19.3.1                   py36_0    defaults
pluggy                    0.13.1                   pypi_0    pypi
ply                       3.11                     pypi_0    pypi
protobuf                  3.11.2                   pypi_0    pypi
py                        1.8.1                    pypi_0    pypi
pyasn1                    0.4.8                    pypi_0    pypi
pyasn1-modules            0.2.8                    pypi_0    pypi
pymupdf                   1.16.10                  pypi_0    pypi
pyparsing                 2.4.6                    pypi_0    pypi
pypdf2                    1.26.0                   pypi_0    pypi
pyqt5                     5.14.1                   pypi_0    pypi
pyqt5-sip                 12.7.1                   pypi_0    pypi
pytesseract               0.3.2                    pypi_0    pypi
pytest                    5.3.5                    pypi_0    pypi
python                    3.6.10               h9f7ef89_0    defaults
python-dateutil           2.8.1                    pypi_0    pypi
pytz                      2019.3                   pypi_0    pypi
pywin32                   227                      pypi_0    pypi
pyxnat                    1.2.1.0.post3            pypi_0    pypi
requests                  2.22.0                   pypi_0    pypi
requests-oauthlib         1.3.0                    pypi_0    pypi
rsa                       4.0                      pypi_0    pypi
scipy                     1.4.1                    pypi_0    pypi
selenium                  3.141.0         py36hfa6e2cd_1000    conda-forge
setuptools                45.0.0                   pypi_0    pypi
simplejson                3.17.0                   pypi_0    pypi
six                       1.14.0                   pypi_0    pypi
sqlite                    3.30.1               he774522_0    defaults
tensorboard               2.1.0                    pypi_0    pypi
tensorflow-estimator      2.1.0                    pypi_0    pypi
termcolor                 1.1.0                    pypi_0    pypi
tesseract                 4.1.1                h328755b_1    conda-forge
urllib3                   1.25.7                   pypi_0    pypi
vc                        14.1                 h0510ff6_4    defaults
vs2015_runtime            14.16.27012          hf0eaf9b_1    defaults
wcwidth                   0.1.8                    pypi_0    pypi
werkzeug                  0.16.0                   pypi_0    pypi
wheel                     0.33.6                   pypi_0    pypi
wincertstore              0.2              py36h7fe50ca_0    defaults
wrapt                     1.11.2                   pypi_0    pypi
xz                        5.2.4             h2fa13f4_1001    conda-forge
zipp                      2.2.0                    pypi_0    pypi
zlib                      1.2.11           vc14h1cdd9ab_1  [vc14]  defaults
zstd                      1.4.4                hd8a0e53_1    conda-forge
```

Comment: Would be helpful if you could edit your answer and add the output of `%conda list`

Comment: @cel done please check

Comment: @cel I did that in my command prompt cuz in jupyter notebook I was getting error `UsageError: Line magic function \`%conda\` not found.`

Comment: I don't see `jupyter` there on the list. Maybe you're running the notebook from another environment (like virtualenv)?

Comment: yes I m running jupyter notebook from virtual env please read question

Comment: @HimanshuPoddar, `%conda` should also work in notebook, maybe you have an older version. You can do `import sys;print(sys.executable)` instead. It should print `C:\Users\HPO2KOR\Desktop\Work\venv\virtualenv\python.exe` along these lines. If it's different, there may be a problem with the currently running kernel.

Comment: @cel... I am facing the same issue.. and as you pointed out, python.exe is not from the venv, rather from the main python path.. And the venv kernel indicator at the top right corner of the Notebook shows up as "venv" but as idle.  How can I fix it  pls..